# C# - Asp.Net Core InvalidOperation Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'AuthMicroservice.Repository.IAuthRepo' while attempting to activate
> 'AuthMicroservice.Controllers.AuthController'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method4(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Please look at these code files

**AuthController.cs**

```
using AuthMicroservice.Models;
using AuthMicroservice.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace AuthMicroservice.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        static readonly log4net.ILog _log4net = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AuthController));
        private readonly IAuthRepo repo;


        public AuthController(IConfiguration config, IAuthRepo _repo)
        {
            _config = config;
            repo = _repo;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Post method for Login
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="login"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Auth login)
        {
            RFQRepo auth_repo = new RFQRepo(_config, repo);
            _log4net.Info("Login initiated!");
            IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
            //login.FullName = "user1";
            var user = auth_repo.AuthenticateUser(login);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                var tokenString = auth_repo.GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
                response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**IAuthRepo.cs**

using AuthMicroservice.Models;

```
namespace AuthMicroservice.Repository
{
    public interface IAuthRepo
    {
        public Auth GetRFQCred(Auth cred);
    }
}
```

**AuthRepo.cs**

```
using AuthMicroservice.Models;
using AuthMicroservice.Provider;

namespace AuthMicroservice.Repository
{
    public class AuthRepo : IAuthRepo
    {
         private readonly IAuthProvider provider;

            public AuthRepo(IAuthProvider _provider)
            {
                provider = _provider;
            }
            public Auth? GetRFQCred(Auth cred)
            {
                if (cred == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                Auth rfq = provider.GetRFQ(cred);

                return rfq;
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuWkw.jpg)

Comment: are you adding IAuthRepo for dependency injection ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are register your `IAuthRepo` service with service collection in `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IAuthRepo, AuthRepo>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define that in a start-up like :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IAuthProvider , AuthRepo >();
}
```

or in minimal API :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthProvider , AuthRepo>();
```